# TypeError: on_command_error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'

Tags: python, discord.py

error:
TypeError: on_command_error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'

but the only problem is that ctx is defined:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(self, error: commands.CommandError, ctx):

    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        return
    elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        message = f"This command is on cooldown. Please try again after {round(error.retry_after, 1)} seconds."
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        message = "You are missing the required permissions to run this command!"
    elif isinstance(error, commands.UserInputError):
        message = "Something about your input was wrong, please check your input and try again!"
    else:
        message = "Oh no! Something went wrong while running the command!"

    await ctx.send(message, delete_after=5)
    await ctx.message.delete(delay=5)
```

or am i just very much stupid?

Comment: Without seeing the actual call to `on_command_error` it is hard to tell. But probably it was called as `on_command_error(error, ctx) instead of `someobject.on_command_error(error, ctx)`. The argument `self` is implied in the second but not the first.

Comment: Perhaps you could include the calling code in your question, to have a better chance of a solid answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the event without cog you need to define it like:

```py
async def on_command_error(ctx, error: commands.CommandError):
```

Comment: Thanks i've tryed everything to make it work, you deserve an upvote :)

Comment: Thanks, could you accept my answer, please?